# Calculate the time difference in the same row dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff, availability

Is there any way to calculate the time difference in SQL between rows within the same column based on the 'DOWN' and 'UP' values like this:

[image]

There are 3 scenarios(that I'm aware of):

- Yellow, Orange and Green: there is a state_id 2(down) and after that a state_id 5(up), so the time difference needs to be calculated between the two rows;
- Blue: there are multiple state_id 2(down) and after that one state_id 5(up), so the time difference needs to be calculated between the first row and last row;
- Red: there is only a state_id 2(down) because it is still down with any update, so the time difference needs to be calculated till the end of the month.

I hope you can help me out.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was first considering to use [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) for this.

But using a cummulative SUM, and the window version of MIN works also for more than 2 DOWN's:

```
-- test reference data
declare @State table (id int, state varchar(4));
insert into @State (id, state) values 
(2,'DOWN'),
(5,'UP')

-- test data, using a table variable
declare @AlertState table (alert_id int identity(1,1), host_id int, state_time datetime, state_id int);
insert into @AlertState (host_id, state_time, state_id) values 
(119, GetDate()-0.32, 2),
(119, GetDate()-0.31, 5),
(119, GetDate()-0.24, 2),
(119, GetDate()-0.23, 2),
(119, GetDate()-0.22, 2),
(119, GetDate()-0.21, 5),
(119, GetDate()-0.15, 5),
(119, GetDate()-0.11, 2);

-- The query
select alert_id, host_id, state_time, state_id,
 diff_min = (
   case 
   when state_id = 5 then 
     datediff(minute, min(state_time) over (partition by host_id, stategroup), state_time)
   when state_id = 2 and stategroup is null then
     datediff(minute, state_time, cast(EOMONTH(GetDate()) as datetime)+1)
   end),
 s.state
from (
    select alert_id, host_id, state_time, state_id,
    sum(case state_id when 5 then 1 end) over (partition by host_id order by state_time desc) as stategroup
    from @AlertState
    where state_id in (2,5)
) q
left join @State s on s.id = q.state_id
order by state_time, alert_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this before is

```
Select a.state_time as downtime, 
    (
        select min(inner.state_time) from tablename downentry where
        inner.state_time > outer.state_time and downentry.state='UP'
    ) as uptime

from tablename upentry 
where state = 'DOWN'
```

Then you need to find the datediff between them, and if uptime is null, the datediff between downtime and 'endofmonth'

It's potentially quite poor performing, so I always wrote the answer out to a data warehouse, but think it gives the results you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

**SQL2012+**

You could try following solution:

```
SELECT y.group_id, host_id = MIN(host_id), start_time = MIN(state_time), end_time = MAX(state_time), diff_minute = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(state_time), MAX(state_time))
FROM (
    SELECT *, group_id = SUM(x.new_group_start) OVER(ORDER BY x.host_id, x.state_time)
    FROM (
        SELECT  *, new_group_start = IIF(a.state_id = 'DOWN' AND ISNULL(LAG(a.state_id) OVER(ORDER BY a.host_id, a.state_time), 'UP') = 'UP', 1, 0)
        FROM    @Alerts a
    ) x
) y
GROUP BY y.group_id
ORDER BY y.group_id
```

**[Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a8e971f3e29e59ffd1a781203f1eeedb)**